# How to mount an ISO file?

Tags: mount

I'm running into trouble trying to mount a large iso:

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-745:~$ sudo mount -o loop /home/dev/Hämtningar/matlab2011a_64.iso /cdrom
mount: warning: /cdrom seems to be mounted read-only.
dev@dev-OptiPlex-745:~$
```

Can you tell me how I should do it?

Comment: Where is the issue? Can you `ls /cdrom`? Note that ISO files are by definition read-only hence the warning.

Comment: Take a look on your desktop or File manager , it may be mounted already as Disk.

Comment: add readonly option `-r` to mount.

Comment: The warning you get about being "mounted read only" is normal! iso files are always mounted read only. you can't modify them. ...(thanks to Anwar Shah down below)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mount an ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1772/how-do-i-mount-an-iso)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try mounting it using a GUI.

Navigate to the `*.iso` file using a file manager, then  `Right click -> Open with Archive Mounter`.

Or you can install the [Furius ISO Mount](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/furiusisomount/). It is available in the Ubuntu Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get install furiusisomount
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Furius ISO Mount - Interface]

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 mounted ISO]

[Furius ISO Mount - Project Page](https://launchpad.net/furiusisomount)

Comment: I think its important to add the case when the ISO file its an UDF image.

Comment: Mounting via "archive mounter" is not a very good method, if you want to run file from the iso. (It is only good to view content). Because, we can't execute file from the iso mounted via "Archive mounter"

Comment: Installing a new software just for mounting an iso image ?

Comment: ⁺¹ because no root rights required.

Answer (score 411):

Maybe, instead of installing additional software, you can use what the system has to this end:

1. **Create a directory to serve as the mount location:**

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/iso
   ```
2. **Mount the ISO in the target directory:**

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop path/to/iso/file/YOUR_ISO_FILE.ISO /media/iso
   ```
3. **Unmount the ISO:**

   ```
   sudo umount /media/iso
   ```

On your desktop will appear the mounted ISO.

Comment: how come that i get message `bash: /path/media/external drive/my.ISO: Permission denied`?

Comment: doesn't work `sudo mount -o loop smb://server/downloads/disk.iso /media/iso` : No such file or directory

Comment: @cipricus it appears that the system can't access your ISO's. The simplest way to overcome this would be to copy the iso file to a local directory first.

Comment: @waspinator try copying the iso file to a local directory first

Comment: @chobok copying it over to a local directory works, but I don't have a file server set up to copy files to my desktop every time I want to use them. I've gone back to Windows for now until this is sorted out.

Comment: @waspinator If you haven't done so already, you could open up new question with your specific issue.

Comment: @Subv3rsion, this method of yours still makes the mount disk as read-only

Comment: @Subv3rsion, you wrote "On your desktop will appear the mounted ISO". Actually it's not on the desktop. It's in Nautilus in the left pane.

Comment: getting the error "you must specify the filesystem type"

Comment: @waspinator you could first mount your samba share and then you can use it as local filesystem (in aspect of current problem)

Answer (score 29):

I found the easiest and fastest way to handle the ISO file in Ubuntu 14.04 was to right click on the ISO file, choose Disk Image Mounter and then simply proceed to the newly opened directory:

[image]

In case you don't have installed, you can use this command in terminal to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Comment: I just realized this exists too! I am a programmer and I like the command line, but this is really the proper, user-friendly, convenient way.

Comment: Still works in 22.04 btw

Answer (score 17):

*I really like Furius ISO Mount, it's a simple application for mounting ISO, IMG, BIN, MDF and NG files.*

- Automatically Mounts ISO, IMG, BIN, MDF and NRG Image Files.
- Automatically creates a mount point in your home directory.
- Automatically Unmounts the Image files.
- Automatically removes the mount directory to return your home directory to its previous state.
- Automatically saves the history of the last 10 images mounted.
- Mounts multiple images.
- Burn ISO and IMG Files to optical disk.
- Generate Md5 and SHA1 checksums.
- Automatically retrieves any previously unmounted images.
- Automatically generates a log file of all commands needed to mount and unmount images manually.
- Localizable (currently Czech, Danish, French, Hungarian, Italian, German, Polish, Slovenian, Spanish and Turkish are available.

[image]

*If 5 stars from 77 ratings is enough to convince you open up your Ubuntu Software Manager and search for Furius ISO Mount.*

Reference Links:

[Furius ISO Mount - Project Page](https://launchpad.net/furiusisomount)

Answer (score 15):

I'm Assuming your iso file name is `matlab2011a_64.iso` in the folder `/home/dev/Hämtningar/`

You can do this to mount the iso file in `/cdrom` folder or create another folder and mount the iso file in it. I'm going to create a separate folder in your home directory. Open a terminal to do all these things

1. Create mount point

   ```
    mkdir ~/mount-point
   ```
2. Mount it with

   ```
   sudo mount ~/dev/Hämtningar/matlab1011a_64.iso  ~/mount-point -o loop
   ```

   This will mount the iso file in the newly created folder named `mount-point` in your home.

   ***Also note, You will be given a warning like `mount: warning: /home/dev/mount-point seems to be mounted read-only`, It is because the iso file always mounts as read-only.*** You can't write to the iso file. You should just ignore that message and proceed forward.

Comment: But why can't you write to the iso file? Shouldn't you be allowed to make modifications, and then repack the .iso?

Answer (score 10):

You can quite easily mount an iso using command-line tools:

First create a directory to mount the iso in with:

```
sudo mkdir /media/myisos
```

(Usually the `loop` module that enables an iso type filesystem to be read is automatically added so you shouldn't need to run `sudo modprobe loop`.)

Now mount your iso by pointing `mount` to its location:

```
sudo mount ~/location/of/iso /media/myisos -o loop
```

It will  give you a warning about the iso being mounted read-only, but that is correct.

You can later unmount it with

```
sudo umount ~/location/of/iso /media/myisos
```

Comment: `loop` module is loaded automatically as far as I know. Also `-t iso9660` is not required anymore in mounting iso file

Comment: I knew this, just a note.

Comment: @Anwar Thanks Anwar- I agree it is useful to make a note of it.

Answer (score 10):

There is a GUI tool built-in albeit menu UI is confusing as it looks like a window title;)

Run "Disks" from your dash. Then from "Disks" menu select "Attach disk image...":
[image: Disks Utility]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ISO Master](http://www.littlesvr.ca/isomaster/), a GUI utility similar to `furiusisomount`. Simply:

```
sudo apt-get install isomaster
```

And then open your `*.iso` file with `ISO Master` from your preferred file manager.

From the website:

> Use ISO Master to:
>
> - Create or customise CD/DVD images
> - Make Bootable CDs/DVDs

Basically, it allows you to add or remove files from the ISO image, then save the changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get read write permissions for copying files from the mounted ISO and do not want to install something else.  Just go into terminal shell, navigate to whereever you mounted your ISO, such as:

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/username/whatever.iso /mnt/iso
```

Than copy the entire mounted directory somewhere else:

```
sudo cp -rf /mnt/iso /home/username/MyMountedISO
```

You could also use

```
cd /mnt/iso
```

Next view the contents

```
ls
```

and than:

```
sudo cp install.img /home/username/MyMountedISO
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `udisksctl` it is part of the system. It mounts your iso in userspace and does not need to be run as superuser. Your file will be mounted to `/media/$USER/` with appropriate permissions.

**Mount iso**

```
udisksctl loop-setup -f my.iso
```

udisksctl will tell you which loop device it is using.

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/loopX
```

where X is the number of the loopdevice your iso is mapped to

**Unmount iso**

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/loopX
udisksctl loop-delete -b /dev/loopX
```

where `X` is the number of the loop device your iso is mapped to. If you forgot you can figure it out by

```
losetup
```

Answer (score 2):

Mounting an iso file is simpler relative to installing it latter. Just to mention that if you want to install latest matlab versions in latest ubuntus, you do not need to mount it the iso, rather extract it there and proceed in installation after making the *install* and */matlab-extracted-folder/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java* executables.

Tested on ubuntu 14.04 and matlab 2014a.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I found [Gmount](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gmountiso/) to be very simple to use for mounting. It has a vintage GUI that is very simple to use and straight to the point.
[gmount GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKG92.jpg)

Install Gmount from the software center then launch it. You can then select your iso image file and choose a mount point where you want to launch the iso file from. You will be prompted for a root password in order to complete the action and thats it.

Comment: But the question is how would you mount an ISO, perhaps you should add how to do this using Gmount..

Comment: Install Gmount from the software center then launch it. You can then select your iso image file and choose a mount point where you want to launch the iso file from. You will be prompted for a root password in order to complete the action and thats it.

Comment: Please add the above to your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just double click it, see:
[How do I mount an ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1772/how-do-i-mount-an-iso/48961#48961)

PS. And, also try double clicking

```
/casper/filesystem.squashfs
```

if the ISO image is an Ubuntu LiveCD ISO etc.

To verify that the functionality IS applicable to these, right click the files to view the options for pertinent operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount an image (or iso) file as read/write as follows.  Set up the loop, then mount with these commands:

```
losetup -fP your.img
#list loop devices
losetup -a
```

If the loop device above was set up as /dev/loop0 then mount cmd is:

```
sudo mount -o loop /dev/loop0 /your/mnt/folder/
```

After this, if you get an error saying the loop device is read only, you can make it writable with this command:

```
blockdev --setrw /dev/loop0
```

If you get an error saying the image is read only, you can remount the image as r/w with this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /your/mnt/folder
```

To remove the mount and loop device:

```
sudo umount /your/mnt/folder/
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Answer (score 0):

A DECADE LATER and still a common newb question & this result is near the top of search.

It can easily be deduced from the initial question that:

1- the person is new and

2- editing an ISO is the goal

->"add readonly option -r to mount.
->Where is the issue?"
->"iso files are always mounted read only. you can't modify them"

->"The simplest way to overcome this would be to copy the iso file to a local directory first."
->"But the question is how would you mount an ISO, perhaps you should add how to do this using Gmount."

->"I've gone back to Windows for now until this is sorted out."

AND THEN EVEN MORE!

Any person new to Linux could (still) benefit from a SINGLE consolidated solution (my personal experience).

(Providing details)
The sum of [these conflicting statements/responses-to-posts-other-than-the initial-question/answers] is not specifically helpful. (reference to several answers)

Not each answer- the SUM of these. Can some one clean up this answer? please...

B/C  I've also gone back to Windows for now until this is sorted out and it seems this is a common occurance.

Yea sorry about the rant - feedback is vital when the process has become run-away.