# How do you mount an hd image made from ddrescue?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image, windows-vista, ddrescue

Today I used ddrescue to make an image of a failed hd. I stored this image on a separate partition on my 500 Gb hd. The partition is sda8 and the filename is `backup.img`.

The image was of an hd that had Windows Vista installed on it. I don't care about the Windows OS on it at all. I simply want to be able to browse the data on it so I can retrieve it and store it elsewhere.

How do I mount this image?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://wiki.edseek.com/guide:mount_loopback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo mount Filesystem.img /home/user/MyFilesystem -o loop
```

is what I used to solve this problem. Below is info from on the loop device [from this answer on Linux Questions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-mount-dos-img-file-4175430554/#post4797805) for those like me who don't/didn't know.

One  further possible type is a mount via the loop device. For example,
the command

> ```
> mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt -t vfat -o loop=/dev/loop
> ```
>
> will set up the loop device `/dev/loop3` to correspond to the file
> `/tmp/disk.img`, and then mount this device on `/mnt`.
>
> If no explicit loop device is mentioned (but just an option `-o loop'  is given), then` mount` will try to find some unused loop device and use
> that, for example
>
> ```
> mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt -o loop
> ```
>
> The mount command automatically creates a loop device from a regular
> file if a filesystem type is not specified or the filesystem is known
> for `libblkid`, for example:
>
> ```
> mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt 
>
> mount -t ext3 /tmp/disk.img /mnt
> ```
>
> This type of mount knows about four options, namely loop, offset, size‐
> limit and encryption, that are really options to  losetup(8). If the
> mount  requires  a  passphrase, you will be prompted for one unless you
> specify a file descriptor to  read  from  instead  with  the  `--pass-fd`
> option. (These options  can be used in addition to those specific to
> the filesystem type.)

Since Linux 2.6.25 auto-destruction of  loop  devices is supported  and
then  any  loop device allocated by mount will be freed by `umount` inde‐
pendently on `/etc/mtab`.

You can also free a loop device by hand, using `losetup -d' or`  umount
-d`.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop devices. Create a loop device upon that file and mount it as if it where a disk. Also, if the disk was partitioned, use the proper offset of the partition(s).

http://wiki.edseek.com/guide:mount_loopback

Comment: Okay I would have posted my answer but I can't for 7 hours. Yes what you said is true:

This site seemed to give me the answer and it worked like a charm:

[Ubuntu Help][1]


  [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/

The command I used was: 

    sudo mount Filesystem.img /home/user/MyFilesystem -o loop

Worked perfectly. I have no clue what the loop thing means so I'll look into that next.
I think this may only have worked because I had only 1 partition?

Comment: Loop devices are special virtual devices which exist for exactly what you want to do: Access a file as if it were a real hardware block device. The mount command you used is a simplified user interface for using them, so it might be intelligent enough to detect partitions and just use the first one. Read its manpage to find out what exactly it did.

Comment: And click the "this answer helped me"-button to rate the answer as valid please :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer here using Disk Image Mounter which has a GUI:
[How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file)
FYI I had a similar problem and realized it was already installed when I right clicked on the .img file (from a damaged CD). Great to recover the one (mp3) chapter which was unreadable.

Comment: As much as it can be gratifying to post an answer that works, if you find one elsewhere that appears to answer the question maybe flag the question as a duplicate. If it isn't a duplicate then it probably won't be answered in the same way.