# How do I install MATLAB via the ISO?

Tags: iso, matlab

I am trying to install MATLAB R2010b to Ubuntu 12.04. I have the ISO file. First I copied it to my PC and then extracted it. Now it seems like I should run the install script. But I could not do that.

Here is the beginning of the install script to give you an opinion if it is not a script and I am doing something wrong:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Name:
#    install -  script file for invoking the Multi-platform installer on Linux.
#
#    Usage: install [-h|help]"
#                              [-javadir <directory>] | [-root <directory>] |"
#                              [-test] | [-v|-verbose]"
#                              -h|-help        - Display arguments."
#                              -test           - Don't actually run the java
#                                                command (only useful with -v)."
#                              -v|-verbose     - Display settings."
#                              -javadir <directory>       - Override default java     root directory."
#                              -root <directory>          - Override default DVD root directory."
#
#              The default settings when no override inputs are supplied are: "
#              -root = <directory containing this script>/../"
#              -javadir = <root>/java/jre/$ARCH/jre'
#
#
# Copyright 2009-2010 The MathWorks, Inc.
```

How can I run this script? I tried to rename it as install.sh and then tried

```
 $ ./install.sh
```

from the command window but I got the following error:

```
root@ghostrider:/home/zero/Downloads/R2010b_UNIX# ./install.sh 
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install.sh: line 562: /tmp/mathworks_7799/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: Permission     denied
Finished
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could you please help me?

Regards

Comment: Do not extract the ISO. It is a CD image, you will need to [mount it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html). Then you can run the installer script.

Comment: @queueoverflow you are right! Installation started now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @queueoverflow - you should move that comment down as an answer

Comment: @aking1012: Too late :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mount an ISO and then install it according to the set up instructions:

- [How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-my-iso-file)
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html

Comment: Please, no link-only-answers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that image is named `R2015b_glnxa64.iso`, simply mount ISO:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/iso
sudo mount -o ro,loop ./R2015b_glnxa64.iso /media/iso
```

run the installation script:

```
sudo /media/iso/install
```

and finally unmount image:

```
sudo umount /media/iso
```

Comment: If you want to install R2017a (two DVDs/ISOs), you should use the same path for mounting both ISO images: (1) mount DVD1 `sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/data/R2017a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /media/iso`, (2) install `sudo /media/iso/install` and wait for a pop-up window to change the disk, (3) mount DVD2 `sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/data/R2017a_glnxa64_dvd2.iso /media/iso`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give executable permission to `sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java`.