# How to mount an ISO image in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file)

I wish to Mount an ISO image and then install a set-up inside the image. Its an ISO of a game btw.

I have tried mounty, Gmount and furious iso and none of them worked.

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this in a Linux distro agnostic way. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop "<path>/image.iso" /mnt
```

Your ISO image will be accessible under /mnt

Comment: I tried ur command line and somehow it worked cause it asked me for password but nothing happened :S  This is what i saw under the terminal hope it will help with the problem.

Comment: When it asks for your password, just type it as usual and press Enter. Password prompts in the terminal are just funny that way ;)

Comment: I did typed the password and somehow it worked in terminal but the Iso didnt mounted anywhere. I checked everywhere on desktop on the disk drives..  anyway here is what happened in the terminal if u can take a look please (http://i.imgur.com/qZHmJ.png)

Comment: OK - you didn't copy and paste correctly... You're missing the -o loop and if the file name contains spaces and characters that need to be escaped you need to encloses it in quotes.

Comment: you shouldn't put it in `/mnt`, it will overwrite anything else there.  you should put it in `/mnt/something`, which I think you need to create first

Comment: This was meant as a one-off, for which it will work just fine. I get your point though, with a small exception that mounting something over other mountpoints won't overwrite any data. The other mountpoints will no longer be reachable until the you unmount the volume mounted on /mnt but that's all.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the built in disk image mounter. Simply right click any ISO file and choose "Open With > Disk Image Mounter."

You can also mount an ISO with the Disk Manager application. The following directions are written for Disks in Ubuntu 12.10, but the Disk Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 is very similar.

Search for Disks in the dash and open it. On the left side, you will see a list with all the disk drives attached to your computer. Click the + at the bottom of the list. This dialog allows you to attach any ISO or IMG file, and it will appear as a new device. From there, click the Mount button (looks like a little Play icon) to mount the volume.

[image: Screenshot of gnome-disks]

Comment: Oh, darn, I am sorry. I missed that you were running Ubuntu 12.04 :(

I will edit my answer.

Comment: ok i tried ur first way which was by right clickin on the iso file and then selecting the "Iso Disk mounter" which its showing "Iso disk mounter (mounty)  <-- which i just installed and its showing error in mouting the ISO. The second way to search the drives from dash board im unable to understand how :S

Comment: but how do I undo this? The disks won't disappear

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. (In Ubuntu 18.04) In the upper right hand corner is there is, what looks like, a minimize button. This is the delete button for removing the device. It will be to the left of the hamburger icon.