# Where to find actual commands for Nautilus "open with" options?

Tags: command-line, mount, nautilus

Actually I want to mount an ISO image (command line) without creating and specifying paths for `mount` command (just to point to ISO and have it mounted).
So if "Disk Image Mounter" is a script - where is it?
And in general where to find actual commands for "open with" options in Nautilus right click menu?

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does the sequence in this answer help?  [http://askubuntu.com/questions/206907/how-to-mount-an-iso-image-in-ubuntu-12-04/206910#206910][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206907/how-to-mount-an-iso-image-in-ubuntu-12-04/206910#206910

Comment: Hm, no. I just can't find what is behind "Disk Image Mounter". Something "automatically" creates mount points (for ISO or HDD) under `/mount/<user>/<disk_name>` and I want to know what script does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every command there's a corresponding `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` or `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`. The command is in the line starting with ´Exec=`.

For "Disk Image Mounter it's the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop`. The ´Exec` line is

```
Exec=gnome-disk-image-mounter %U
```

so the command is

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter %U
```

where `%U` gets replace by a list of URLs for the files you have selected, for example

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter file:///tmp/myimage.iso file file:///tmp/other.iso
```

---

See the [Freedesktop Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html) for more about `.desktop` files.

See the [gnome-disk-image-mounter manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnome-disk-image-mounter.1.html) for more about `gnome-disk-image-mounter`.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I looked for