# How do I install MATLAB R2012b via the ISO file?

Tags: software-installation

I want a quick and simple tutorial on "install MATLAB R2012b via the ISO file on my ubuntu 12.10". As you know i have the iso file. Consider that i'm new to linux and ubuntu.
Help me please!

Comment: Did you google this first? there are many excellent articles available... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB and http://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file should help you. Please update your question if you get stuck.

Comment: yes, i search this and i read a lot of istrunctions including what you link. but i know that matlab r2012b only supports ubuntu 12.04 and it has some problems with 12.10. so i asked if some one install r2012b on 12.10 and help me to do so.

Comment: Try installing it first if you already know the basic instructions on how to install it and ask again here if there is any problem encountered when you run it.

Answer (score -3):

Best solution is to try an alternative. [QtOctave](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtoctave/). It works almost fine for me. But if you want to definitely use Matlab, the long but perfectly working solution is to install XP through [VirtualBox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox-qt/) and get Matlab running in seamless mode.