# Unable to mount ISO in write mode

Tags: mount, iso, read-only

I tried to mount my Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit image using the following command :

```
sudo mount -o rw,loop /home/varun/Downloads/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso /media/cdimage
```

But I gets the following warning :

```
mount: warning: /media/cdimage seems to be mounted read-only.
```

Help me to eliminate the warning.

Comment: See also:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40124/how-to-mount-freebsd-9-0-iso-file-writable-mode and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/iso-file-readonly

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ISO files are always mounted as read only. So copy files from the mounted ISO to another folder and then make changes you want. You can then use mkisofs to generate a new ISO from the modified folder.

Comment: I copied the file and entered the path using this command to jigdo :jigdo [/media/cdimage]: /home/varun/Downloads/Ubuntu . But it shows "Enter the no.of images". What should I enter ?

Comment: did you follow which tutorial?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JigdoDownloadHowto

Answer (score 2):

As explained in other answers, ISO images apparently always get mounted as read-only.

If you want to make changes to your `*.iso` image, use a GUI such as `ISO Master` or `Furius ISO Mount`. See [How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file) for details.

Comment: Is there anything like that which still functions in 2023?