# Is it possible to mount an iso in writable mode ?

Tags: mount, 16.04

I would like to know if it is possible to `mount` in mode `writable`. I mean to mount a content of an `iso` file in order to modify it in `/media/USERNAME/NEWFOLDER`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.

[Avinash-Raj](https://askubuntu.com/users/202806/avinash-raj) said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/390610/518562), [flagged as dupe]

> ISO files are always mounted as read only. So copy files from the
>   mounted ISO to another folder and then make changes you want. You can
>   then use mkisofs to generate a new ISO from the modified folder.