# How to turn write protection off of /media/cdrom0

Tags: mount, permissions, virtualbox, read-only

I have a mid term exam for my Cyber Security and Network Systems class here in 6 hours, so I must get to sleep, and hope someone can help me out in the meantime! I am currently running Kali Linux using Vbox. Alright, long story short, my **VBOXADDITIONS is (read only?) Anyhow, it says Write protected.**

I have tried to do `mount -o rw,remount /media/cdrom0`
It then tells me: `mount:cannot remount /dev/sr0 read-write, is write-protected`

I then tried to do `sudo hdparm -r0 /media/cdrom0`
and it says

```
/media/cdrom0:setting readonly to 0 (off)
BLKROSET inappropriate ioctl for device
BLKROSET inappropriate ioctl for device
```

So, in reality, I cant get this dang thing installed correctly to be able to have full screen to utilize the work space at my best ability. Someone, please help, thanks!

Comment: Why do you thing you are not able to install it correctly without W support? Addition ISO doesn't need to be edited in order to use it. Simply mount it as cdrom and execute autorun.sh.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page: "The name is an acronym which stands for "Compact Disc Read-Only Memory". Computers can read CD-ROMs, but cannot write to CD-ROMs which are not writable or erasable." Good luck with the exam.

Comment: Besides that: Kali Linux is not our cup of coffee.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zVU89

Answer (score 4):

CD-ROM devices are, by nature, read-only. Hence the name CD-**ROM**.

With this in mind, it's not possible to directly alter the data on a CD or a mounted ISO. Instead, you have to extract the ISO or copy the data somewhere else where you can manipulate it:

```
cp -R /mnt/cdrom/ ~/Desktop/CD-Data/
```

This limitation was carried over to the ISO system (and VirtualBox) as a way of properly emulating the hardware, [including the write protection](https://askubuntu.com/q/390608/208574) that comes with it.

---

However, for the purpose of installing VirtualBox Additions, you don't actually need to be able to write to the ISO/install media. Simply running the install script present within it is more than enough to get your system online properly. You can [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/208574) for detailed instructions.