# Mount .ISO using the terminal

Tags: mount, iso

i've been trying to mount an .iso according to a guide i read here, but every time i run the command `sudo mount -o loop /home/varbo/Downlaods/Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.iso /media/iso` i get the same (usage) error:

```
Usage: mount -V                 : print version

... usage and options deleted ....

Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
For many more details, say  man 8 mount .
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: See similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file/410663#410663.

Comment: @landroni true, but the crux of the OP problem is spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here's that you can't have spaces among the command or the terminal interprets it as a separate command/statement, what you have to do is rather simeple, just rename your file from `Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.iso` to `Windows_7_Ultimate_SP1.iso`, and do the same with command.

The command should look like this `sudo mount -o loop /home/varbo/Downlaods/Windows_7_Ultimate_SP1.iso /media/iso`

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: although you can rename the file, consider education the OP on how to use spaces in file names if they so desire.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind for future reference, thanks for taking the time to give me the advice.

Answer (score 9):

Your iso has spaces, so you have to quote or escape them:

```
sudo mount -o loop '/home/varbo/Downlaods/Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.iso' /media/iso
```

or

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/varbo/Downlaods/Windows\ 7\ Ultimate\ SP1.iso /media/iso
```

The spaces will be automatically escaped if you use tab completion

sudo mount -o loop /home/varbo/Downlaods/Windows<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> /media/iso