# How to convert the iso file into rar or zip or tar?

Tags: iso, compression, zip, extract, rar

Is there anyway to extract iso or convert it to zip, rar, or tar file?

I have a big `.iso` file on my remote server and I just want a file from it, not all of that; unfortunately I do not have root access, so it's my problem.

Comment: Try installing this sudo apt-get install gmountiso

Comment: Is your server configured to allow non-root mounting with `udisks`?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing things up: an ISO is a data dump (often from a dvd/cd/bd). You mount ISO's as you would mount a hard disk. And when mounted you can "cd" into the directories and copy files from it.

If you are unsure about command line install software that can mount ISOs. Examples: furius, gmount-iso, acetoneiso, gisomount. All are available in Ubuntu Sofware Center and will show up if you search for "iso mount".

---

Regarding mounting ISO: [How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file) There is a command line method in there too. If you mount it in your own /home/$USER/ folder there is no need for `sudo`. Example:

```
mount -o loop file.iso /home/$USER/Downloads/
```

will mount file.iso in your `~Downloads`.

Comment: thnx for your reply, but I just access to my server in text mode(terminal), is there any command to see and copy files from it?

Comment: as I said, I have not access to root for mount !

Comment: on my server I have not enough permission and I can't download it because it's too heavy !

Answer (score 0):

Without root access you'll have to grab the entire file, move it to a box where you have root access, and then mount the iso to pull just a single file out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can can convert an Iso file into a rar, tar or zip or any other compression file format using an online file converter, such as [ISO to RAR](https://www.freefileconvert.com/iso-rar), [ISO to tar](https://www.freefileconvert.com/iso-tar) , and [ISO to Zip](https://www.freefileconvert.com/iso-zip).

You can format your file if its size is up to 300MiB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to extract a few files from an .iso file, you can just open it using the "Archives" application.