# ISO file is empty (no files or folders)

Tags: iso

I downloaded Fallout 3 iso file and mounted and there isn't any files or folders. Size of iso file is 5.9 GB

Comment: i don't have computer with windows :/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/193632/261706

Comment: Fallout 3 has an iso file... right....

Answer (score 0):

That ISO contains an UDF file system and it can be mounted using [Furius ISO Mount](https://launchpad.net/furiusisomount). You can install it in Ubuntu from Software Center or from Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install furiusisomount
```

When mounting the image, choose the **loop** method.

[image]

You will need root privileges.

After you're done with mounting you'll stumble on the next issue. Isn't that game a Windows only application? I guess you know how to use Wine.

Comment: I used Sagar Panchal method. I found it tutorial for Fallout 3 installation :D