# Why mounted ISO is empty?

Tags: mount, iso

I have downloaded and use the Furius Iso Mount following a [procedure](http://onetransistor.blogspot.gr/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) to create a Windows 10 USB bootable stick from Ubuntu.

The problem is that when I am clicking at the mounted file there is **NOTHING** inside! I used the Furius Iso Mount as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686692/iso-file-is-empty-no-files-or-folders)... It seems easy to use so I don't believe that I was wrong there.

I thought maybe its something about the iso file but when I tried with 2 another I got the same problem.

I tried also to mount it from terminal like this... `sudo mount -t udf -o loop *iso /mnt`
  and it produced **mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only** but when I opened the file it was empty.

I noticed some differences though from other guys on youtube that were using the Furius Iso Mount:

```
1) When I clicked the mount-button it didn't ask for root permissions.
2) When my file was mounted it appeared only in /home and not in left 
   list of the file manager where all the mounted files are listed.
```

I really **need the files inside** the mounted ISO file, so what can I do?

Comment: Just tested and it works fine with the standard Disk Image Mounter - as mentioned in the guide you linked - and an Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: The windows 10 ISO is not empty? Or just includes a ReadMe.txt?

Comment: It shows all the files and folders it should: boot / efi / sources / support (folders) and autorun.inf / bootmgr and bootmgr.efi / setup.exe , everything as it should be. Perhaps the problem is with the ISO you're using. Mine come directly from Microsoft so it's fine.

Comment: Yep, mine as well... Its Windows 10 Education official. Don't really know what's the problem, thanks for help @CelticWarrior!