# Why after mount Windows 10 iso it only inlcudes a ReadMe.txt?

Tags: mount, windows, iso, windows-10

I am trying to mount a Windows 10 Education iso to create a bootable USB, using Ubundu.

When I mount via Archive Manager the file only contains a ReadMe.txt. That only happened to another Windows 10 iso file.

Comment: Are you sure the download isn't corrupted?

Comment: I downloaded the windows 10 Education iso from Microsoft, its official! Maybe I should download again...

Comment: that's what I'm saying. Official downloads can get corrupted as much as unofficial ones.

Comment: Both times? That's the weird part of it!

Comment: it's always possible, especially if you have a bad connection. How exactly are you mounting it and what does the readme contain?

Comment: I mount it with the Archive mounter and I cannot understand what the readme writes. I opened it with nano but I got only weird symbols!

Comment: "Mounting" with Archive Manager does that.  What I commented in your other question was about the standard Disk Image Mounter, also mentioned in the guide you linked there.

Comment: @Skemelio where exactly are you downloading this from? How big is the downloaded ISO?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I also tried with the Furius Iso Mount but then the file was completely empty!

Comment: @Zacharee1 I downloaded from Microsoft's dreamspark! The file is 3.9GB. If I only had a windows machine I could have done it right now. I want to make my computer dual-boot windows+ubuntu

Comment: @Skemelio Why use Education then?

Comment: I'm intrigued, why don't you use the Disk Image Mounter (default and already installed)? It just works, I don't even have Furious installed.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I use Education because Microsoft is giving it for free. It does not include any other of Windows 10. Maybe I should install Win7?

Comment: @Skemelio install whichever you prefer. However, it seems that you need something that supports the UDF filesystem type. I'd just try burning it to a CD/USB without bothering to mount it or anything.

Comment: My God! Mounting with Disk Image Mounter did the work! I can see all the files! Jesus cannot believe my eyes! Thanks @CelticWarrior and also Zacharee, appreciated your time!

Comment: @Zacharee1 The OP is trying to make a bootable  USB to install Windows from Ubuntu following a guide linked in his other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/837129/why-mounted-iso-is-empty . The said guide mentions Disk Image Mounter explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Zacharee1, at last I am going to continue the effort to install windows through my Ubuntu system

Answer (score 1):

Mounting with the Disk Image Mounter would do the work, as @CelticWarrior mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. The solution was to mount it manually as UDF type, like:

```
mkdir win
sudo mount Win10_1909_EnglishInternational_x64.iso win/ -o loop -t udf
```