# Can I extract a program or script from an ISO image or bootable drive?

Tags: iso, extract

Is it possible to extract a specific script from an .iso or bootable drive?

I want to use a Ruby script would come pre-installed if I were using Kali Linux, but without actually using Kali Linux.

Is it possible to pull it from `kali.iso` in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Use any tool to mount the ISO then browse it like any other driver?

Comment: So, really you are asking [How to mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file)

Comment: This is not actually off-topic, because the goal here is not to use Kali Linux, but to copy a file off of a Kali Linux ISO image or installation medium. This question is more about *not* using Kali Linux; if one is running Kali Linux, one already has the immediate access to the scripts it ships with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount the `.iso`, then use regular file copying tools:

Here's an example, with a different `.iso`

```
$ mkdir ~/mnt/iso
$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro ipfire-2.19.i586-full-core114.iso ~/mnt/iso
$ df ~/mnt/iso
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0        174656 174656         0 100% /home/w3/mnt/iso
```