# How can I watch a blu-ray with the .iso file extension?

Tags: video

How can I play a blu-ray with a `.iso` file extension?

What player would you recommend to watch a blu-ray with the `.iso` file extension? I do not have any media players installed.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You can use VLC for instance. You can mount `iso` as a disk.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file explains two methods to mount an ISO in your file system. Once that's done, then you can launch the video with the excellent VLC app https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html