# How to use a loop device as non-root

Tags: loop-device

Do I need to have root privilege in order to create and use a loop device?  Suppose I have an ISO file *dir.iso* containing an image of the directory *dir*. I want to mount *dir.iso* as a directory *data* and access its files. I've done this in the past using a loop device, but I don't remember how.

Comment: IIRC creation of a loop device can be done by non-root users, but mounting needs root, since otherwise you can gain root by mounting to system directories.

Comment: A very similar question on U&L SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202609

Comment: You can open/mount ISO using Disk Image Mounter, see https://askubuntu.com/a/519858/66509 .